# Lower bound for complex polynomial beyond circle or radius R

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, upper-lower-bounds

If we have a polynomial with $c_i$ a complex number
$$c_nz^n + c_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \cdots + c_1 z + c_0$$
then $$|P(z)| > \frac{|c_n|R^n}{2}$$
When |z| > R for some R

I have tried using the triangle inequality where I obtain,
$|P(Z)| \leq |c_n||z|^n + \cdots + |c_0|$. But I seem to keep getting stuck. Any hints on how to move forward? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$\frac{|P(z)|}{|z|^n}
=\left|c_n+\frac{c_{n-1}}z+\frac{c_{n-2}}{z^2}+\cdots+\frac{c_0}{z^n}\right|.$$
Show that if $|z|$ is large enough, then
$$\left|\frac{c_{n-1}}z+\frac{c_{n-2}}{z^2}+\cdots+\frac{c_0}{z^n}\right|<\frac{|c_n|}2$$
etc.

Answer (score 4):

This is part of Growth lemma, we have
$$|p(z)|=|z^n(c_n +\dfrac{ c_{n-1}}{z} + \cdots + \dfrac{c_1}{z^{n-1}} + \dfrac{c_0}{z^n})|$$
for $|z|=r$
$$|p(z)|\geq r^n\left(|c_n|-|\dfrac{ c_{n-1}}{z} + \cdots + \dfrac{c_1}{z^{n-1}} + \dfrac{c_0}{z^n})|\right)$$
but
$$|\dfrac{ c_{n-1}}{z} + \cdots + \dfrac{c_1}{z^{n-1}} + \dfrac{c_0}{z^n})|\leq\dfrac{1}{r}\left(|c_{n-1}+\cdots+|c_0|\right)=\dfrac{\alpha}{r}$$
therefore
$$|p(z)|\geq r^n\left(|c_n|-\dfrac{\alpha}{r}\right)$$
now let $r>\dfrac{2}{|c_n|}\alpha$.

Comment: (+1) nice. Would you be interested in supporting the [proposal of a "Math Challenges"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/119894/math-challenges) site? Please feel free to drop in [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82675/area-51-proposal-math-challenges) for discussion :)

Comment: @TheSimpliFire thank you very much.