# Proving that a complex power series is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $p(z)=a_0+\dots+a_nz^n, n\geqslant 1, a_n\neq 0.$
I want to show that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a complex differentiable function, where $f=1/p(z)$. I already showed that there is an $R>0$ such that $\left|z\right|>R$ implies that $\left|z^nf(z)\right|<2/\left|a_n\right|$.

Any hints to get me going?

Comment: Hint: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2957694

Comment: I don't see what the hint is...

Comment: What *means* that a function $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is *complex* differentiable?

Comment: What if $p(z) = z?$

Comment: You want to show $f$ is entire? How? Wouldn't that be contradicting the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra?